# Creating a booking date search to connect sandbox Commerce Availability to Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

We have tried a number of modules for a rental system, and we have stumbled upon a sandbox project called [Commerce Availability](https://drupal.org/sandbox/camdarley/1762222) which is supposed to add an availability field to Commerce line items. This sounds like something we could use, except customers would then need to be able to search dates for available items within that range. It seems like that tidbit is missing. For our (and client's) purposes, it's better and less confusing for everyone if we stick with Commerce and avoid using Rooms or Merci or AGReservations in addition to Commerce. We feel Commerce is more straightforward. How would we go about creating the date search and connecting that further to Commerce Availability and then Commerce?

Comment: It looks like you are asking to teach you about writing Comemrce plugins and design code? This question is so broad I don't know where to start and if it's even worth it.

Comment: I really just wanted a pointer like "Look at x module" or something similar. I wouldn't ask someone to work for free.